# React items.map is not a function when items is an array?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

Loading in an `API` and I'm getting `.map` isn't a function. Been looking through every example and followed them exactly but still getting this error. The error is of course happening at the `.map` in the ul tag

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=18&difficulty=easy&type=boolean"
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({ isLoaded: true, items: json });
      });
  }

  render() {
    var { isLoaded, items } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <ul>
            {items.map(item => (
              <li key={item.results.question}>{item.results.question}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual data is coming in `json.results`, so you need to set `json.results` in state like,

```
this.setState({ isLoaded: true, items: json.results });
```

You need to iterate array like,

```
{ items.map(item => (
     <li key={item.question}>{item.question}</li>
))}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5yo614)

Comment: Check the demo.